# Restful Web Services & Multiple Return Types

Tags: asp.net, rest

I'm building my first Restful Web Services using the Visual Studio WebAPI solution template.  For my model, I have a single Customer class with the following fields:

- CustomerID
- FirstName
- LastName
- Email
- Street1
- City1
- State1
- Country1
- ZipCode1
- Street2
- City2
- State2
- Country2
- ZipCode2

Based on our requirements I need the following methods and return data:

- GetCustomerFromID - returns all customer fields
- GetCustomerEmailFromID - returns Email
- GetCustomerMainAddress - returns Street1, City1, State1, Country1, ZipCode1
- GetCustomerSecondAddress - returns Street2, City2, State2, Country2, ZipCode2

Therefore, I built a single Controller called CustomerController that contains these methods and returns a Customer object in all 4 methods.  With this approach, the GetCustomerFromID returns a Customer object with all fields containing a value.  However, the GetCustomerEmailFromID returns a Customer object with only a single field value and the rest are NULL.

Is this approach ok, or is there a better approach/best practice where I'm only returning the fields required by each method?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your way feels heavy - because you have a bunch of endpoints for slices of the same resource.

Yahoo uses what they call views:

> A resource might provide different views of the same data. To specify
>   a view, append the view query parameter to the URI. For example, to
>   retrieve the tiny view of the contacts for the user of GUID 4467, call
>   HTTP GET on the following URI:
>
> https://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/4467/contacts?view=tinyusercard
>
> Note that the view parameter applies only to singleton (not
>   collection) resources.

Another good resource Apigee has a couple of big providers compared (http://apigee.com/about/blog/technology/restful-api-design-can-your-api-give-developers-just-information-they-need)

- Linked In: `/people:(id,first-name,last-name,industry)`
- Facebook: `/joe.smith/friends?fields=id,name,picture`
- Google: `/dogs?fields=name,color,location`

I much prefer an API like those.

Further help here: [How to do partial responses using ASP.Net Web Api 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20059191/how-to-do-partial-responses-using-asp-net-web-api-2)