# ASP.Net Web API partial response base on a role

Tags: asp.net-core, roles

I know this is an old question, but could not find an answer for ASP.Net Core. I have ASP.Net Core web api application with role-based membership. Suppose we have an enitity from database with such fields:

```
public class Transaction
{
    public int Id { get; set;}

    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public string ManagerId { get; set; }

    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

And controller action:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin,Manager,RegularUser")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Transactions(TransactionsRequest request)
{
    var response = await _repository.Find(request, User);
    return Ok(response);
}
```

My goal is to query and return partial result based on a role:

- For Admin role I need to return all transations with all fields
- For Manager role I need to return trasactions for current manager (based on managerId) without UserId field
- For RegularUser role I need to return trasactions for current user (based on userId) without ManagerId field

I think it is simple to make three different actions, each one for specific role. But what if my role number will grow?

Comment: And what is the problem? I fail to see what the problem is. Just return whatever you need based on the criteria you described....

Comment: You can do it in a single action or separate actions, but as you said, a single action is going to be easier to manage if the number of roles increases.  Just put a conditional/switch statement in the controller (or service) and alter your query/output based on the role.

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro I cannot understand how it is better to implement - single method with many if-conditions inside and many role-specific response models (or a partial response which is better) OR many per role methods?

Comment: I think you need to have a single Action in your controller. This action decides what to return... Otherwise you would be giving the responsibility to the caller.... Even further you are NOT returning views... just sets of data... so all you are adding is a new filter criteria...  In my opinion you are missing a layer in your design because you are going directly to the repository... If you had a business layer this could be logic that goes in there.

Comment: also I am not sure what you mean by "partial response"... I dont think that is concept that applies here...Partial usually refers to a Partial Html View.... But you are NOT returning Html Views from an API... You are returning most likely JSON

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro thank you for response! Just omitted business logic layer for simplicity. By partial response I mean not showing part of the response for some roles. Something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20059191/how-to-do-partial-responses-using-asp-net-web-api-2

Comment: to remove the fields you have a couple of options:  1 just make them null.  2 create models for the different scenarios... i would say do not overthink this... i do this all the time by just setting the fields to null